# comparison operator optimization in C

Tags: c, if-statement, optimization, operators

I just came across an interesting case but I can't find any information about it and I was wondering if anyone here might know the answer.

So I have the macro `INT_MAX` which is the largest possible number an int can store on my operating system.

the following if statement has some weird behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    int maxValue = INT_MAX;
    printf("INT_MAX: %d\n", maxValue);
    printf("INT_MAX + 1: %d\n", maxValue + 1);
    
    if (INT_MAX < maxValue + 1) {
        printf("no overflow\n");
    } else {
        printf("overflow\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

by running this program we get the value of INT_MAX and the overflow of INT_MAX followed by overflow.

if I switch `INT_MAX` with the variable `maxValue` the 'else' is executed instead and "no overflow" is printed. I assume this means that the if statement or < operator is checking if both the left and right values passed to it are the same and instead of doing the actual calculation it simply returns 1 as it sees that on the right hand side we're adding a positive value to the same variable.

So is this what is actually happening or is it something else entirely?

Thanks!

edit: INT_MAX not MAX_INT

Comment: `INT_MAX` or `MAX_INT`? Anyway, `maxValue + 1` overflows and from there on you're out of luck

Comment: Signed integer overflow invokes *undefined behavior*. Searching for reference...

Comment: @Jabberwocky made an edit, it's all INT_MAX

Comment: So if `INT_MAX` is the maximum value an `int` can store, what value do you expect the `int` expression `maxValue + 1` to be? And how could it be *greater* than `INT_MAX`?

Comment: did you mean `if (maxValue < maxValue + 1 )`?

Comment: Do you mean if you change `if (INT_MAX < maxValue + 1)` to `if (maxValue < INT_MAX + 1)` the output changes?

Comment: @FredLarson When `maxValue == INT_MAX`, `maxValue + 1`  doesn't store anything. It causes the Matrix to break and nothing makes sense anymore (and this "nothing makes sense anymore" travels back in time too). That's what undefined behavior is. You see, the compiler is allowed make code transformations that assume the overflow never happens (=> hence all the time traveling craziness).

Comment: Do not expect the rules of math to be followed when code involves _undefined behavior_. (UB) like `INT_MAX + 1`.  Compilers take advantage of UB to emit effient code, providing unexpected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I assume this means that the if statement or < operator is checking if both the left and right values passed to it are the same and instead of doing the actual calculation it simply returns 1 as it sees that on the right hand side we're adding a positive value to the same variable.
>
> So is this what is actually happening or is it something else entirely?

That is an optimization that compilers commonly make. It is likely it is what is occurring in your example, although proving this particular optimization is responsible rather than some other behavior in the compiler would require diving into compiler internals. [Godbolt does show that Clang and GCC compile the following code to a constant return value of 1:](https://godbolt.org/z/noPYGj)

```
int foo(int x)
{
    return x < x+1;
}
```

The assembly generated by Clang is:

```
foo:                                    # @foo
        mov     eax, 1
        ret
```

Answer (score 2):

When the calculation result goes beyond the range that the result type can represent, *undefined behavior* is invoked and anything is allowed to happen.

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5 Expressions 5:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
> result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
> type), the behavior is undefined.

The result of `maxValue + 1` when `maxValue = INT_MAX` will go beyond the range of `int`, so *undefined behavior* is invoked here.

On the other hand, if you use unsigned integer, calculating `UINT_MAX + 1` won't invoke *undefined behavior* because results of unsigned integer calcuhation is defined as modulo to the range of the types.

Quote from N1570 6.2.5 Types 9:

> A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow,
> because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is
> reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be
> represented by the resulting type.

Therefore, this code will print `overflow` even after replacing `maxValue < maxValue + 1` to `UINT_MAX < maxValue + 1`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    unsigned int maxValue = UINT_MAX;
    printf("UINT_MAX: %u\n", maxValue);
    printf("UINT_MAX + 1: %u\n", maxValue + 1);
    
    if (maxValue < maxValue + 1) {
        printf("no overflow\n");
    } else {
        printf("overflow\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```